# Are there existing well-maintained vagrant chef recipes for Magento?

Tags: magento, virtualization, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to get up and running with a virtualized development environment for magento, and hitting a few snags.

I found this magento cookbook, but it's throwing an error at the moment, I based it off of the lucid32 box:
http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/magento

```
[Fri, 27 Apr 2012 19:21:51 +0100] DEBUG: Loading cookbook windows's library file:       /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/windows/libraries/ruby_19_patches.rb
[Fri, 27 Apr 2012 19:21:51 +0100] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Fri, 27 Apr 2012 19:21:51 +0100] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[Fri, 27 Apr 2012 19:21:51 +0100] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: LoadError - no such file to load -- win32/open3
```

Did a bit more searching and ran into this one - which actually I think is using puppet, not chef - but I don't have a preference at the moment, particularly if both are free.
https://github.com/tonigrigoriu/magento-cookbooks/blob/master/Vagrantfile

I ran it, and hit the following error:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` v-csc-1 /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
```

I did make one change in the Vagrant file which was commenting out the `config.vm.network("33.33.33.33")` line.

Perhaps I'm expecting this configuration to be a little easier than I should, especially given that I'm a dev not a devops, but if there are any chef/puppet recipes out there that are relatively well supported and maintained, would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this one http://www.kingletas.com/2012/09/magento-and-vagrantup.html ?

Comment: Hey thanks. Actually just read this the other day!  I'm not sure that he's providing an actual full recipe that can be plugged in?  Seems more like a tutorial.

Comment: What about this one https://github.com/BjoernSchotte/commerce-dev-environment?

Comment: Thanks man!  I think I noticed that yesterday on Twitter as well :)  Looks really good.  I haven't been doing much with vagrant lately but I'm guessing that will finally be the answer to this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Vagrant/Chef recipes mentioned in Magento PHP Developers Guide:
https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/magento-php-developer%E2%80%99s-guide

I suspect the author moved his repository here:
https://github.com/amacgregor/magento-1.7.0.2

With regard to your issue of mounting, I suspect that you should try *NOT* use a host-only IP address in your Vagrantfile, and instead try port forwarding as a temporary fix.

Please note, as far as the Chef Recipes and Virtual Machines are involved, I have not yet found *anything* that works, including base images from hashicorp/atlas.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to your vagrant file, you may need to destroy the VM and recreate it, before making your change. Otherwise things might get out of sync.

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a vagrant magento in https://github.com/rjocoleman/vagrant_magento.
Its used by https://github.com/rjocoleman/vagrant-magento-mirror, that is a project with a magento instance setuped by vagrant_magento. You can clone the magento-mirror and execute the `vagrant up` command